# is it required to do unlocking of bootloader before installing and upgraded rom for sm-g550t galaxy on5 and then reroot

Tags: rooting, rom-flashing, bootloader, bootloader-lock

i want to know,in order to upgrade from my rooted Samsung ON 5 SM G550T, to Nougate 7.00, will i have to re-root the phone process again. Currently my phone is rooted but i think my boot loader is locked, which will require me to unlock my boot loader; in order to do a upgrade to Nougate,if i understand?
 If the boot loader is locked how do i check? to see if its locked.
On a previous occasion i tried to flash xposed program (rom) and got a binary 1 error is this related to a locked boot loader, or diff issue. If so how do fix a binary 1-2 error message.

Comment: That all very much depends. If the ROM you want to upgrade to is an official one (ie. provided by Samsung), you won't need to unlock the bootloader. You might have to root again after the upgrade, though, unless you have some "[Root Keeper](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_sysmaint#group_988)" taking care for that.

Answer (score 0):

As Samsung hasn't updated your device to android 7.0 so in order to upgrade your android version you have to unlock bootloader then flash a custom recovery.

Then you can flash any 7.0 custom rom.